# React Router routes but show error message

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using react router 1.0.0-rc1 and redux.

this are the routes:

```
<Route path=""component={Body}>
    <Route path="machines/:id" component={SingleMachineView}/>
    <IndexRoute component={Dashboard}/>
    <Route path="*" component={Dashboard}/>
</Route>
```

this is the link:

```
<Link to={`machines/${machine.machine_id}`}> 
  {machine.name} 
</Link>
```

this how the router is started:

```
class Root extends React.Component {

  render() {

    const history = createHashHistory();

    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        {() => <Router history={history} children={Routes}/>}
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Root/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Everything works as expected, but when I click the link and the new view is rendered I still get an error message in the console:

`Warning: Location "machines/id2" did not match any routes`

Also the error message doesn't appear when I load the app with path `localhost:8080/#/machines/id2`

Comment: what's the exact url in the browser when you click on the `Link`?

Comment: `http://localhost:8080/#/machines/id0?_k=cjqdch`, btw I have no idea where the `?_k=cjqdch` comes from.

Comment: @AndreasKöberle [what is ?_k=cdjk](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/basics/Histories.md#what-is-that-_kckuvup-junk-in-the-url)

Comment: Dont know, something adds this to end of the url automatically. Thought it came from the router.

Comment: Seems the that the `history` module adds this, when using `hashHistory`: http://rackt.github.io/history/stable/HashHistoryCaveats.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the link as to start with a `/`:

```
<Link to={`/machines/${machine.machine_id}`}> 
  {machine.name} 
</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my use of the router either the router or the browser adds a leading `/` as in your example in the comments.

I'd suggest you create a root `route` with a `/` instead of a blank string:

```
<Route path="/"component={Body}>
    <Route path="machines/:id" component={SingleMachineView}/>
    <IndexRoute component={Dashboard}/>
    <Route path="*" component={Dashboard}/>
</Route>
```

Comment: what I don't understand is that the error doesn't match the url :(